# How can I use Groupbox Tag?

Tags: c#, tags, groupbox

I'm programming in C# in Visual Studio and I'm using a Groupbox in which I insert a number of TextBoxes, depending on data I retrive from the database. As I don't know how many Textboxes there are, I store the amount in the Tag Property of the Groupbox. In another routine I use this value. But I'm receiving an error message. First case:
If I try to use this value directly:

```
int Nbancos = Gb_Bancos.Tag;
```

Visual Studio says that "it's not possible to convert inplicitly type object in int."
Second case:
If I make an explicit convertion:

```
int Nbancos = (int) Gb_Bancos.Tag;
```

There's no error during compiling but when I run the program I receive the error message:
"System.InvalidCastException:specified conversion is not valid".
Third case:
I tried a conversion to string:

```
string Nb = (string) Gb_Bancos.Tag;
int NBancos = int.Parse(Nb);
```

And I received the same error message above.
I know it must be a silly error, but please, can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Tag is neither int nor string. What do you store in tag. What value? What type? Show the code, please.

Comment: Yes, as @OlivierRogier said. int Nbancos = (int) Gb_Bancos.Tag; should work if Tag contains a number.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that the Tag property is always initialized with a number (even when there are no TextBoxes) then you can simply write

```
int nb = Convert.ToInt32(Gb_Bancos.Tag);
```

but do you know that you can avoid all this using

```
int nb = Gb_Bancos.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Count();
```

of course this approach is not faster than the previous one but I think it will save a lot of works on that Tag property.

Comment: The property Tag has always the number of textboxes in Gb_Bancos (a groupbox). It's created with zero.

Comment: Steve. I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you! Your second suggestion also works.